# How to convert hanging hand grip strength to pounds per square inch?

Tags: resistance

I know the title may be off putting such as the matter of this question, but is there any reasonable way to find out how strong one's crushing hand grip strength is from the amount of weight resistance from hanging on a bar?

For example, see, I do not own a gripper, so I thought that support grip (used for hanging) can possibly transfer or equate yo some comparable form of crushing hand strength in pounds per square inch.

Like, for example, a 400 lb person can support their body weight hanging from a bar or beam, and I weigh 200 lbs so I would need an extra 200 lbs to match that equivalent support grip. Can the support strength be translated in to squeezing, crushing grip strength, as applied on a gripper?

Answer (score 2):

Hanging doesnt really test your forearm strength, I mean its a part but there are other factors that would influence your "test".

Simply trying to hold onto a heavy dumbell would be a better indicator.

Note there are different types of grip strength [(Crushing, pinch, support)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grip_strength). And even the "[Farmer's Walk](http://www.bodybuilding.com/fun/strongman13.htm)" would only test one type.

Its probably easier to just pay for a visit to a physio to get them to test it for ya with the proper equipment.

Or Buy [one](http://www.ebay.com.au/itm/HAND-GRIP-STRENGTH-DYNAMOMETER-STRENGTH-POWER-MEASURING-DYNAMOMETRE-TRAINING-/300902836465?pt=AU_Strength_Training&hash=item460f34e8f1&_uhb=1)? They are like $30

Answer (score 0):

Nah if you think about it it's not the same type as squeezing simply because it doesn't cover the full range of motion. It's easy to close a gripper the first little bit but then it gets dramatically harder the closer to closed it gets.

Comment: Can you provide a better and more thorough explanantion about that? Also, I've removed the link to your site. Please see our [help section](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/help/behavior) about promotion.